# How can I list out my Chat draft messages in MS Teams, using powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In the microsoft graph API, you can get your chat messages via calls to get-mgchat. However, I don't see a way to find drafts. Somehow the app knows there's a draft, but how? If I create a draft then run this, it comes back with no messages.  (Yes, I know that LastUpdatedDateTime is not necessarily when the last messages was sent, but the last time the chat was changed)

```
$RequiredScopes = @("Chat.ReadBasic", "Chat.ReadWrite")
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes $RequiredScopes
$startdate = (get-date).AddDays(-2) #look for chats less than 5 days old
$meetingchanged = (get-date).AddDays(-2) #lookback for meeting changes, only include meetings with changes more recent than this
$myrecentchats = @() 
write-host "getting the recent meeting chats"

#how to test out get-mgchat and get the full error
#try {get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "lastUpdatedDateTime gt '$oldtime' and ChatType eq 'meeting'" -ErrorAction Stop -Debug } catch { Write-Host $_.Exception | fl * }

$oldtime = $($meetingchanged.ToString("s") + "Z")

#somewhere between 1.23 and 1.27 they made it so using quotes around $oldtime stopped working (...gt '$oldtime' and...). No quotes now! And you have to COMPLETELY uninstall,#
# then use -requiredversion 1.27.00
$myrecentchats = get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "lastUpdatedDateTime gt $oldtime and ChatType eq 'meeting'"
write-host "getting all oneonones"
$myrecentchats += get-mgchat -all -PageSize 50 -filter "ChatType eq 'oneOnOne'"
write-host "getting all group chats"

$all_chat_info = foreach ($chat in $myrecentchats) {
    #is $chatinfo even used? Doesn't seem to be 
    #$chatinfo = get-mgchat -ChatId $chat.id #get base details about the CHAT itself 
    #set some details about the chat itself for the later query
    $chatname = $chat.Topic
    $members = $chat.Members
    $chattype = $chat.chattype
    $recentchatmessages = get-mgchatmessage -ChatId $chat.id  -Filter "lastModifiedDateTime gt $($startdate.ToString("s") + "Z")"
    #and now use select expression to add the above fields and parse the below fields, stripping out HTML (but I can't seem to only get the first line in OGV)
    $recentchatmessages | select @{Label='LastModified';Expression={($_.LastModifiedDateTime.tolocaltime())}}, @{Label='ChatName';Expression={($chatname)}}, @{Label='members';Expression={($members)}}, @{Label='ChatType';Expression={($chattype)}}, 
    @{Label='From';Expression={($_.from.user.displayname)}}, @{Label='ChatID';Expression={($chat.id)}}, @{Label='Body';Expression={ ($_.Body.content -split '\n')[0] -replace '<[^>]+>',''}}, @{Label='LUDT';Expression={($chat.LastUpdatedDateTime)}}
}
$all_chat_info|ogv
```